# How to perform logging in Flink jobs?

Tags: logging, apache-flink

I am working on a very simple use case where i want to check the data in a `DataStream`. I would like to understand if there is a better way of logging.Because the below way of logging looks very ugly and adds an extra stage.

```
DataStream<Conversation> stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer.getKafkaConsumer());
        stream.map(conversation -> {
            logger.info("Read from Kafka source conversationId: {} and content: {}",conversation.id,conversation.time);
            return conversation;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement a mapfunction class, and then print the log in the class

```
DataStream<Conversation> stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer.getKafkaConsumer());
            stream.map(new MyMapFunction()
            });

public class MyMapFunction extends RichMapFunction<T> {
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public T map(...) throws Exception {
        logger.info(xxxx);
        return xxx;
    }
}
```

Also you can use printsink directly

```
DataStream<Conversation> stream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer.getKafkaConsumer());
        stream.print()
```

Comment: What is the difference in logging inside map and using MapFunction?

Comment: printing the stream prints only to console isn't it?